# Can I restart my WordPress site without using a different domain name?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, google-search-console, url, wordpress

I'm getting problems with crawling my site in Google Webmasters Tools. I'm seeing weird URLs that end with my domain, like:

`/tag/sugar/www.k2ost.com`

`/tag/melody-day/www.k2ost.com`

and also like this:

`/tag/.../www.mydomainname.com`

`/post/.../www.mydomainname.com`

That of course will result in a `404` error code.

I've been searching for a question on this site that has the same problem as mine, and user *sidh* states that it was a URL masking problem [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/43398).

So I want to completely restart my WordPress site, but I want to use my current domain. Can I do that?

I've already read [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/39667) related question, but it's for creating the same site on a different domain. Can I restart my WordPress site using the same domain?

Comment: By "restart" do you mean to replace your WordPress site with new content and URLs, reset the indexed URLs in Google Webmaster Tools, or something else?

Comment: Are you inadvertently linking to these URLs on your site? Are these URLs appearing in Google's search results (since they return a 404 I doubt it)? In GWT's 404 report, from where these URL's being linked from?

Comment: @dan yes i want to reset all the indexed on google webmaster tools is there anyway to do this? :)

Comment: @w3d no im never make that URL. Its GWT's that crawl that URL i dont know what GWT's crawl that make www.mydomain.com is appear on the end of the URL. Its not appearing on Google search result :(

Comment: If these URLs are not indexed (they do not appear in the SERPs, so they are not indexed) then there is no need to "restart" your site (whatever you mean by that). However, you need to work out how Google is finding these URLs to begin with. If it's as a result of another site linking (incorrectly) to you then there is not much you can do about it, apart from informing the site in question (or perhaps a 301 redirect). What does the GWT 404 report show for the pages that link to these URLs (click the URL and then the "Linked from" tab)?

Comment: @w3d Its many of error like 1000 errors like that all. x.x
the tag/sugar/www.k2ost.com is linked from tag/sugar URL from "Linked From" tab. idk why x.x

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a plugin gone wrong issue. I would use something like Xenu's Link Sleuth

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xenu%27s_Link_Sleuth

and take a base line look at your site. Then disable all plugins and crawl again. If the offending links are in the base line but not in the results without plugins then one of your plugins is definitely causing problems. If none are found then it's possible that these malformed URLs are being introduced by site maps or RSS feeds and those should be checked too. Also consider flushing your cached Wordpress rewrite rules and inspecting them to ensure that they are correct.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=flush+rewrite+rules

Comment: how to know what plugin is get error? im already use the flush rewrite rules plugin and it shows the rule and url what should i do? thanks for ur answer! :)